# Extracting number from URL

Tags: php, regex

In every meta title of my blog articles I want to add "News - {number from URL} - MyWebsite.pl". I don't know how to dynamic extract numbers from URL of articles.

I have:

```
<title>News - <?php preg_match('/^[1-9]*$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);echo($matches); ?> - MyWebiste.pl</title>
```

but it returns "News - Array - MyWebsite.pl"

My URL's have structure like: http://mywebsite.pl/info/news15 and number "15" I want to add to meta title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to have the number at the end, you have to remove the start with `^` sign, you should note that if you want to have numbers including `0` you should add it to the range `'/[0-9]*$/'` instead of `'/[1-9]*$/'`:

```
<?php
preg_match('/[1-9]*$/', 'http://mywebsite.pl/info/news15', $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

this will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
)
```

**so for your code to work, you should have it like this:**

```
<title>News - <?php preg_match('/[1-9]*$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);echo($matches[0]); ?> - MyWebiste.pl</title>
```

Comment: What if there is a 0 in the number?

Comment: @ROOT Ok, now I have "News - Array([0] => 15) - MyWebsite.pl" but I want "News - 15 - MyWebsite.pl". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it **without reguler expression**,

```
<?php
$url = 'http://mywebsite.pl/info/news15';
$result = filter_var(basename($url), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
?>
<title>News- <?=$result;?> -MyWebiste.pl</title>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Fo2BO